# Using a Button_Click event to change textbox content using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I don't even know if that's the right title for this but anyway. I'm switching from WinForms and trying to learn WPF and the MVVM methodology.

I have a custom class, `Incident`, used to store data about incidents that occur that my team must respond to. I am building a View to display the data in instances of that class to a user, as well as allow that user to manipulate it. There are several pieces of `DateTime` data that need to be displayed - `Start`, `End`, `Notification_Received`, `Actions_Taken`. I need to have a small button that will put `DateTime.Now` into each associated `TextBox` as well as change the underlying value of the currently loaded instance of the `Incident` class.

I'm trying to figure out how to do this. With WinForms, I would've just set `TextBox.Text` and `Incident.Start` (etc) to `DateTime.Now` all in the same `Button_Click` function, but my understanding of MVVM is that I'm not supposed to do this, instead I should bind the `TextBox` to the VM and update the value of the VM.

This is where I'm stuck. I'm pretty sure I'm good on how to do the binding, but not the part where I change the value of the VM from my `Button_Click` function. Please assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct - the view-model should control the change, and the textbox should update through a binding.

In the MVVM pattern, code-behind is rarely used. Instead of a `Button_Click` method, you need a command binding:

```
<Button Command="{Binding SetAllDatesToNowCommand}"/>
```

The command will be executed when the button is pressed. `SetAllDatesToNowCommand` is a command handler - it should be an `ICommand` property on your view-model:

```
public ICommand SetAllDatesToNowCommand { get; private set; }
```

I generally tend to use `RelayCommand` from the [MVVM Light Toolkit](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) to create command handlers, because the syntax is clean and very simple. The command handler is initialized in your view-model's constructor. The handler method passed to `RelayCommand` is where you should set properties on the selected `Incident` object:

```
public YourViewModel()
{
    this.SetAllDatesToNowCommand =
        new RelayCommand(this.ExecuteSetAllDatesToNowCommand);
}

...

public void ExecuteSetAllDatesToNowCommand()
{
    this.selectedIncident.Start = DateTime.Now;
    // etc.
}
```

If the bindings on your textboxes are correctly set up, and the properties that are being set are firing appropriate `PropertyChanged` events, they should be updated when the properties are set in the command execution method.

However, I'd suggest that you should have a view-model for `Incident`, which implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. The command outlined above would be a property on that view-model. Setting, for example, the `Start` property on that view-model should set the property on the `Incident` object it is the view-model for (the "model" object), and should also raise a `PropertyChanged` event. Otherwise, your `Incident` class will have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and the line between model and view-model classes becomes less clear.

Comment: How do I do this without using this `RelayCommand` from MVVM Light Toolkit? I am using VS Express 2012 and there are no downloads for it.

Comment: Also, again remembering that I'm entirely new to MVVM/WPF, this seems like an awful lot of code to accomplish something it would take TWO lines to do in WinForms and without following MVVM. What is the benefit of all this extra effort? I'm having trouble seeing it.

Comment: You can add MVVM Light Toolkit to your solution from NuGet - right-click on your solution and select "Manage NuGet Packages for Solution". Otherwise, you can [implement a simple `Command` class](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/274982/Commands-in-MVVM#hdiw1) yourself.

Comment: It can seem like a lot more code, but there are definite advantages.  Some examples: Your view-models are testable, unlike code-behind. This in itself is a huge benefit. Having your textboxes bound to view-model properties means that you can change a property's value from anywhere, and anything bound to that property will automatically update. In code-behind, you'd have to do a lot of that wiring manually. Commands can be automatically routed to different view-models, just by setting up the correct bindings.

Comment: What do you mean by "testable"? I feel like what I *think* you mean by it and what you actually mean are not the same thing.

Comment: I mean that you can cover your view-models with unit tests to verify more of your UI behaviour. For example, you might have a unit test that executes `SetAllDatesToNowCommand`, checks to make sure that the `Start` property on an `Incident` was set to an appropriate date, and then checks that a `PropertyChanged` event was raised for it. Once your view-models are covered with tests, you just have to make sure that the bindings are correctly hooked up. This kind of testing is next to impossible with code-behind.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've bound the form to your ViewModel. Therefore you have a property in your ViewModel of Start. You want to bind a field to that

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding Start}/>
```

or

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding Incident.Start}/>
```

Depending on how you expose Incident. To update Start you have to do two things. Use a command on the button.

```
<Button Command="{Binding TestCommand}">Test</Button>
```

In your ViewModel you'd define the command.

```
private RelayCommand _testCommand;
public RelayCommand TestCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _testCommand ?? (_testCommand = new RelayCommand(TestUpdate, CanRunTest));
    }
    set
    {
        if (_testCommand == value) return;
        _testCommand = value;
    }
}


public bool CanRunTest()
{
    return some boolean test that defines if the command can run now;
}

private void TestUpdate()
{
     Incident.Start = DateTime.Now;
}
```

RelayCommand is a helper method you can find in MVVMLight. Also see Josh Smith for info on RelayCommand.

Second, you will need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on the Incident model or look up ObservableObject and make your Start property look like this.

```
public class Incident : ObservableObject
{
    private ObservableCollection<WordLetter> _start;
    public virtual ObservableCollection<WordLetter> Start
    {
        get { return _start; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _start) return;
            _start = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```